# Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have downloaded the `HLS` videos via `DataSource.Factory` and I have implemented the `DRM` support for both drm enabled and non-enabled videos via `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory`. But when I am updating the app and playing the existing downloaded videos via drm enabled `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory` I am getting the below exception as:

```
Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:580)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: Input does not start with the #EXTM3U header.
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:250)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:70)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.FilteringManifestParser.parse(FilteringManifestParser.java:46)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.offline.FilteringManifestParser.parse(FilteringManifestParser.java:30)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:179)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Has anyone else has faced such type of issues?